# ArrayList : remove method throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I'm currently working thorugh the AP CS elevens lab, which has you develop your own card and deck classes in order to simulate a card game. I'm currently writing a shuffle method that takes a `Deck` object and randomly shuffles the `Card` objects in it. Here is my method so far:

```
public void shuffle() {
 ArrayList<Card>copy = new ArrayList <Card> ();
 for (int i = cards.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
   int d = (int)(Math.random()*i);
   copy.add(cards.get(d));
   cards.remove(d);
 }
size = cards.size();
cards = copy;
}
```

`cards` is an ArrayList that has been initialized with multiple `Card` objects. This code works fine, but only if the `cards.remove(d);` line is not present. Why is this? And how can I fix it?

If this helps, here is the constructor class for `Deck` that you are given:

```
public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) {
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
        for (String suitString : suits) {
            cards.add(new Card(ranks[j], suitString, values[j]));
        }
    }
    size = cards.size();
    shuffle();
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong when the problematic line is present?

Comment: The program compiles, but as soon as it runs I get a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` error.

Comment: And it runs fine if that one line isn't present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code

```
for (int i = cards.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
```

This will enter the loop when the size is 0 (when there is no card left), hence the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Change the `>= 0` to `> 0` in your loop condition.

```
for (int i = cards.size(); i > 0; i--) {
```

Note that there is already a [`shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) method for `Collections` which take `List` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You try to remove a card when there aren't any left (i.e. when `cards.size() == 0`).  Fix it by changing the loop termination condition to `i > 0`.

Alternatively, I'd probably write the loop a bit differently:

```
while (!cards.isEmpty()) {
    int d = (int) (Math.random() * cards.size());
    copy.add(cards.remove(d));
}
```

That seems a lot clearer to me.

Comment: Note, too, that there is `java.util.Collections.shuffle()`, which will do this job.  I mention it only as a comment because I suppose that implementing the shuffle yourself is part of the point of the exercise.